# select row values as column based on GROUP BY column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with data like this:

```
Id           Value
-------------------------
01           Id01-Value1     
01           Id01-Value2 
02           Id02-Value1
02           Id02-Value2
03           Id03-Value1
```

What I want is

```
Id          Value1          Value2
--------------------------------------
01          Id01-Value1     Id01-Value2
02          Id02-Value1     Id02-Value2
03          Id03-Value1
```

I tried sql `PIVOT` but it is not for this type of problem I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use `min()` and `max()`:

```
select id, min(value) as value1,
       (case when min(value) <> max(value) then max(value) end) as value2
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Answer,

```
SELECT ID
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN Value ELSE '' END)Value1
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN Value ELSE '' END)Value2
FROM(
    SELECT ID,Value
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value)RN
    FROM Your_Table
    )D
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, `PIVOT` is exactly what you need - if you can bear it's damned syntax! It is relatively flexible but also unwieldy.

```
SELECT 
    id
    ,[1] AS Value1
    ,[2] AS Value2

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id
            ,value
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value ASC) AS column_number

        FROM
            YOUR_TABLE_NAME

    ) AS src

PIVOT
    (
        MAX(value)
        FOR column_number IN ([1],[2])
    ) AS pvt

ORDER BY
    id
```

This will sort the rows in the `value` column alphabetically, and assigns column numbers accordingly in sequence (but you could include different logic, for example to nip the column number off the right-hand side of the value, or name the columns according to the value itself rather than numbering them). NULL values will be returned for any column that doesn't have a value.